# Remove Double Quotes and Comma in a String in Complex CSV Data Using Dataweave

Tags: csv, mule, dataweave, mule-esb, mulesoft

I have CSV based Incoming Request Data from Salesforce. It has Columns which contains Characters like Double quotes and Comma. All the columns are encased in double quotes and contains characters like Extra Quotes and Comma.

Input and output payload are of CSV format in Dataweave.

*Sample Request*: Includes Extra Quotes and Comma

```
Id,AccountId,Contact,Name,Email,Phone,Fax

"","","","WM. C. "Rocky" Hudson JR., CIC","test@gmail.com",""
```

```
Column with the Extra Quote and Comma is: {"Name" : "WM. C. "Rocky" Hudson JR., CIC"}
```

*OUTPUT of the Dataweave Transformation Sample (For Testing I have output to JSON)*

```
[
  {
    "Name": "WM. C. ",
    "Email": " CIC\"",
    "Phone": "test@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

*Excepted Output*: Remove Extra Quotes and Comma

```
[
  {
    "Name": "WM. C. Rocky Hudson JR. CIC",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "Phone": ""
  }
]
```

*Note: 
1. I have tried replace and regex in dataweave but not getting the desired output*

Any help on this is really appreciated and Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This csv is not well formed. Currently DW csv parser will not handle this. What Salesforce request did returned this?

Comment: @machaval Thanks for replying to post. Yes Salesforce is returning this format as listed above in sample request. Name Column is which breaking as it has additional Comma and Quotes in it and outputting the result as listed in Excepted Output above after DW Transformation.

**DW Code**
`%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=true,quoteValues=true
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
 Name: payload01.Name,
 Email: payload01.Email,
 Phone: payload01.Phone
 
})
`

Comment: CSV isn't formatted well, you might aswel get more issues if u handle this in mule development. it is a good idea to have pipe seperated file `(psv)` output from salesforce or tab seperated.This should be handled in DBMS instead

Comment: @Ven Thanks for your reply. I will consider your points and work on it accordingly.